# Not able to import camelot in Python 3.7(Anaconda) in MacOS Catalina

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, anaconda, python-camelot

My environment specs

- > `python --version`
  >
  > Python 3.7.6
- > `anaconda --version`
  >
  > anaconda Command line client (version 1.7.2)
- > `sw_vers`
  >
  > ProductName:    Mac OS X
  >
  > ProductVersion: 10.15.2
  >
  > BuildVersion:   19C57

I installed `camelot` from  [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/camelot-py)
 using the command below.

```
conda install -c conda-forge camelot-py
```

Attaching the logs when I try to import `camelot` for pdf parsing and text extraction purposes.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/~/PycharmProjects/Utilities/rosblancos/pdf-utilities/pdf-element-extractor.py", line 1, in <module>
    import camelot
  File "/~/.conda/envs/Utilities/lib/python3.7/site-packages/camelot/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .io import read_pdf
  File "/~/.conda/envs/Utilities/lib/python3.7/site-packages/camelot/io.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .handlers import PDFHandler
  File "/~/.conda/envs/Utilities/lib/python3.7/site-packages/camelot/handlers.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .parsers import Stream, Lattice
  File "/~/.conda/envs/Utilities/lib/python3.7/site-packages/camelot/parsers/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .lattice import Lattice
  File "/~/.conda/envs/Utilities/lib/python3.7/site-packages/camelot/parsers/lattice.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ..image_processing import (
  File "/~/.conda/envs/Utilities/lib/python3.7/site-packages/camelot/image_processing.py", line 5, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: dlopen(/~/.conda/envs/Utilities/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libglib-2.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /~/.conda/envs/Utilities/lib/libharfbuzz.0.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libharfbuzz.0.dylib requires version 5601.0.0 or later, but libglib-2.0.0.dylib provides version 0.0.0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I googled the error above and found [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/471). However, I am unable to solve this issue as I am not able to find out what I need to do with the file named `libglib`.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this worked for me:

```
pip install opencv-python
```